# Go doesn’t understand how the http.Server Handler calling functions which attached to an empty struct

Tags: go, handler, httpserver

I have this code of a simple web server, but I don’t understand this code:

Handler:app.routes(),

```
const webPort = "80"

type Config struct {}

func main() {

    app := Config{}
    log.Printf("Starting broker service on port %s\n",webPort)
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: fmt.Sprintf(":%s",webPort),
        Handler:app.routes(),
    }

    err := srv.ListenAndServe()
    if(err != nil) {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

And in the routes file:

```
func (app *Config) routes() http.Handler {
    mux := chi.NewRouter()
    mux.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://*","https://*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "DELETE","PUT","OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Accept","Authorization","Content-Type","X-CSRF-Token"},
        ExposedHeaders: []string{"Link"},
        AllowCredentials:true,
        MaxAge:300,
    }))

    mux.Use(middleware.Heartbeat("/ping"))
    mux.Post("/",app.Broker)

    return mux
}
```

This is working and the routes() function called when request received,
but how does this routes() know to be triggered when it is attached to an empty struct?

```
app := Config{}
```

From where does the app know about routes()?

What is the func `(app *Config)` in the function?

Comment: routes is a method defined on the Config struct, as shown in your second code snippet. This method returns an http.Handler, hence you can use it as struct field in the server struct.

Comment: i dont see it defined on the config struct .. is it in the definition of the func or somthing ?

Comment: If you look at the first line in your second code snippet you see `func (app *Config) routes() http.Handle`. This is the syntax to define a method on a type, in this case on the Config type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes have been attached to the HTTP server as shown below.

```golang
srv := &http.Server{
   Addr: ":8081", // port
   Handler: app.routes() // a handler to invoke
 }
```

`routes` is a method of `Config` struct. We can still call the `routes` methods as in your code even when `Config` is empty.

```golang
 cfg := Config{}
 r := cfg.routes()
```

`Config` struct is acting as a method receiver here.

Comment: Tnx, few things i dont understand , what do you mean method receiver ? for me ( coming from c++ and java ) its defining empty struct . from where did the Config knows about the routes() method ?

Comment: @user63898 `func (app *Config) routes() http.Handler {/*...*/}` is a method declaration. It "attaches" the function in question to the `*Config` type. In the context of this method, `app` is known as the _method receiver_; you'd call it `this` in traditional OO languages.

Comment: Please refer this https://go.dev/play/p/Xp29ddR7Eag. In this example, `(a Animal)`  is called as the **receiver** and `Animal` is called as the **receiver type**.